# Google Script and rot13 (alphabetic substitution with macro)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a code that is working perfectly in js, but I'm trying to implement in on Google Script (based on js) without luck, GScript doesn't like the 4th line "Syntax error" and probably will not like 5th and 6th either, what is wrong?

```
function rot13(str) {
  var input     = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ abcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyzÁÉÍÓÚáéíóú-,';
  var output    = 'ABpqCjDEWiFbvGHIrsJaKLMÁNúdkOxoPÓáQy.ñRcSTnÚtUVéfghmíwXuYZóeÉÍlz-,';
  var index     = x => input.indexOf(x);
  var translate = x => index(x) > -1 ? output[index(x)] : x;
  return str.split('').map(translate).join('');
}
```

UPDATE
So according to @Sirko suggesting me about changing the `=>` I redo the code as follows:

```
function rot13(str) {
  var input     = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ abcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyzÁÉÍÓÚáéíóú-,';
  var output    = 'ABpqCjDEWiFbvGHIrsJaKLMÁNúdkOxoPÓáQy.ñRcSTnÚtUVéfghmíwXuYZóeÉÍlz-,';
  var index     = function (x) { return input.indexOf(x) };
  var translate = function (x) { return index(x) > -1 } ? output[index(x)] : x;
  return str.split('').map(translate).join('');
}
```

> Resulting in ReferenceError: "x" is not defined. (line 5)

Comment: Are you sure they support arrow syntax? Maybe just switch to plain functions and you should be fine.

Comment: updated with your suggestion, but getting another error..

Comment: the function for `translate` is wrong., try `function( x ) { return index(x) > -1 ? output[index(x)] : x; }`

Comment: Your function body is `index(x) > -1 ? output[index(x)] : x`, not `index(x) > -1` — that would be the conditional of the ternary operator.

Comment: thank you very much, with your help I solved it and it's working perfectly fine :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use lambda function when you dont want to use "this", arguments variable and prototype in others cases you can use lambda functions.

```
function rot13(str) {
  var input =
    "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ abcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyzÁÉÍÓÚáéíóú-,";
  var output =
    "ABpqCjDEWiFbvGHIrsJaKLMÁNúdkOxoPÓáQy.ñRcSTnÚtUVéfghmíwXuYZóeÉÍlz-,";
  var index = function(x) {
    return input.indexOf(x);
  };
  var translate = function(x) {
    return index(x) > -1 ? output[index(x)] : x;
  };

  return str
    .split("")
    .map(translate)
    .join("");
}

rot13("a");
```